# Highest number of WordPress Custom Page Templates?

Tags: theme-development, pages, page-template

I'm little bit rookie in understanding WordPress core. But I would like to know that, is there any limit or should we limit to how many custom "page" templates we make in our custom theme?

My WordPress website is currently using about 50 custom coded page templates, I would like to know its performance, side effects and when should I stop creating these templates and restructure the whole website so that it uses less templates.

Also each template provides it's unique feature in my scenario, that's the main reason they are distributed seperate template files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such limit. Of course you can't say it's unlimited, because in IT everything has some limits (due integer size, number of files in directory, maximal length of filename, and so on).

There won't be any big performance side effects. WordPress stores list of templates in cache (AFAIR), so it should be OK. (Of course again, if you'll create 1000000 templates, then the select on page editor will take long time to load...)

But, there is one limit - will the user be able to select proper template. And are these templates really necessary - maybe there should be some options in the editor to modify the look and feel of given template, and so on.